# Pausing script while waiting for Docker container and printing updates

Tags: console, linux, shell, status-monitoring

I'm looking to improve it in brevity, readability, and simplicity. Basically, I'm just looking for a more elegant solution. What improvements can I make?

```
i=0
while true; do
    OUTPUT="$(docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health.Status}}' su-apache)"
    if [ $OUTPUT = '"healthy"' ]; then
      echo
      break
    fi
    echo -en "\r\033[KWaiting $i seconds for su-apache to finish starting... Current health: $OUTPUT"
    let "i++"
    sleep 1
done

echo 'Environment started successfully.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using Bash,
then it will be more elegant to replace the `while` loop with a counting `for` loop:

```
for ((i = 0; ; i++)); do
    # ...
done
```

I'm guessing that you're using Bash anyway from the `let "i++"` syntax,
which will not work with simpler shells like Dash.

Note that the various flags of `echo` are not portable.
For a more portable solution, replace it with `printf`.

Lastly, the indentation is inconsistent: some blocks are indented with 4 spaces, others with 2. It would be better to indent consistently (I like 4 spaces).

Comment: Thanks for this. It really helped a lot! How are things normally done here on CodeReview? How long do people usually wait before accepting an answer? Should I edit my revised code into my question?

Comment: Hi, and welcome! I don't recall a rule for this. A few days on average is usually about right, I guess. We don't edit code in the question, as that would invalidate answers. See [this page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center for more details, and enjoy the site!